Issue with memory pointers in class mapping for simplified SELECT queries
I'm working on improving the SELECT functionality in my application by mapping a class and storing relevant information into a record. Here is an example of my class properties:
[Field('ID'), PK, AutoInc]
property ID: Int64 read FID write FID;
[Field('NOTA_ORIGINAL')]
property NotaOriginal: string read FNotaOriginal write FNotaOriginal;
[Field('NOTA_TROCA')]
property NotaTroca: string read FNotaTroca write FNotaTroca;

Part of my mapping function looks like this:
for lProperty in lType.GetProperties do
begin
  if (lProperty.HasField<Field>) then
  begin
    lMappedField.Field := lProperty.SearchAttribute<Field>.FieldName;
    lMappedField.PK := False;

    if (lProperty.HasAttribute<PK>) then
    begin
      lMappedField.PK := True;
      FPKKey := lProperty.SearchAttribute<Field>.FieldName;
      FPropertyPK := lProperty;
    end;

    lMappedField.AutoInc := (lProperty.HasAttribute<AutoInc>);

    if lProperty is TRttiInstanceProperty then
    begin
      PropInstance := TRttiInstanceProperty(lProperty);
      MemAddress := nil;

      if PropInstance.IsReadable then
      begin
        // Check if lProperty is directly tied to a field
        if (IntPtr(PropInstance.PropInfo^.GetProc) and PROPSLOT_MASK) = PROPSLOT_FIELD then
        begin
          // Obtain the memory address of the directly associated field
          MemAddress := PByte(FObjeto) + (IntPtr(PropInstance.PropInfo^.GetProc) and (not PROPSLOT_MASK));
          lMappedField.Mem := MemAddress;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    FMapping.Add(lProperty, lMappedField);
  end;
end;

Here’s the record structure I'm using:
TMappedField = record
  Field: string;
  PK: Boolean;
  AutoInc: Boolean;
  Mem: Pointer;
end;

The mapping is stored in a variable: FMapping: TDictionary<TRttiProperty, TMappedField>. I also have other variables for quick access to key information:
FSQLTable: string; // class attribute
FPKKey: string; 
FPropertyPK: TRttiProperty;

This mapping system works well and saves time for various classes. However, I have a concern regarding the Mem pointer that I save, which I use to simplify the SELECT queries. Here is an example:
function TMCRTTILibORM.Load: TMCRTTILibORM;
begin
  FSelectText.Clear;
  FSelectText.Add(' SELECT FIRST 1 ' + FPKKey + ' FROM ' + FSQLTable + ' ');
  Result := Self;
end;

function TMCRTTILibORM.Where(const pProperty: Pointer; const pValue: Variant): TMCRTTILibORM;
var
  lPropertyField: TPair<TRttiProperty, TMappedField>;
begin
  for lPropertyField in FMapping do
  begin
    if lPropertyField.Value.Mem = pProperty then
    begin
      // Add WHERE or AND to SQL query
      if FSelectText.Count > 1 then
        FSelectText.Add(' AND ' + lPropertyField.Value.Field + ' = ')
      else
        FSelectText.Add(' WHERE ' + lPropertyField.Value.Field + ' = ');

      // Handle different types (Integer, Float, String, Enumeration, etc.)
      // Example for tkInteger:
      FSelectText.Add(VarToStr(pValue)); 

      Result := Self;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TMCRTTILibORM.Open: Boolean;
var
  lQuery: TCustomQuery;
begin
  lQuery := TCustomQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    lQuery.SQL := FSelectText;
    lQuery.Open;

    // Update object with primary key value
    if lQuery.RecordCount > 0 then
    begin
      FPropertyPK.SetValue(FObjeto, lQuery.FieldByName(FPKKey).AsInteger); // Example for tkInteger
      Result := LoadObject; // Populate the object
    end;
  finally
    lQuery.Free;
  end;
end;

With this, I can simply call:
Result := ItemObject.Mapping.Load
  .Where(@ItemObject.ID, pID)
  .Open;

Concern: A senior developer mentioned that the Mem pointer stored in my record could be invalidated by Windows if memory is managed or relocated, causing the comparison in the Where function to fail.
My current approach maps the object only once and retrieves its attributes on-demand. All my tests so far have been successful, but if this memory management issue is real, I may not be able to rely on this approach.
Question: Is the concern about the memory pointer (Mem) valid in this scenario? Could Windows memory management indeed alter the pointer, and if so, what would be a better way to maintain this mapping for select queries?

Never heard of Windows ever fiddling around with object memory unless told by the application itself. While the physical memory address may change (could be even in the page file), the address the process uses will always be valid until f.i. the instance is destroyed. Your approach looks pretty valid for me.

I agree with Uwe Raabe. On Windows by applications are not accessing computer memory directly but instead through Virtual Memory System. Virtual Memory System allows OS to extend memory capacity by allocating some of the disk space for memory allowing your computer to be concurrently running multiple application at the same time even thou combined they would require more memory than the size of your RAM. ...

... Of course in order for this to be able to work OS needs to be able to physically move your application from one physical memory location to another without breaking the application. This done in a was so that your application is always requesting memory access (either for reading or writing) using the Virtual Memory Address and then OS translates that to actual Physical memory address based on which memory blocks were assigned to your application.

@UweRaabe , @SilverWarrior , if I add this object to a TObjectList while keeping the mapped memory pointer, could that cause any errors?

If the TObjectList owns the instance, it can be destroyed making any other pointer invalid, but that is always the case when instances are freed while any variable points to that instance. Basically, you can always do stupid things...

Thanks, @UweRaabe. Actually, my question was more about whether adding the object would change the pointer. However, I tested it, and even inside a list, it remains the same as what was mapped in my record, which is perfect for the functionality.

@missingNO If your Mem pointer points to object instance then it will be fine until this specific object is destroyed as Uwe Raabe already commented above. But if it points to a record within some array since just deleting any array record before will shift position of your record within the array an thus within the memory. Another thing might be array relocation that happens when you resize dynamic array and it isn't located in big enough continuous memory block to fit new array size.
